# Getting error: undefined reference to function Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have been trying to solve this issue for more than two days, but still no luck.

I have no idea what is wrong, I need just to set up a simple NDK project, but it has already taken a tremendous amount of time.

The problem is that I am getting

```
error: undefined reference to 'firpm(unsigned int, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&, double, int)'
```

Here is my root CMakeLists

```
# Cmake Minimum Version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
project(EcgProcessing)
# Add nested cmake files
include(libs/CMakeLists.txt)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# ECG Audio Processor library
add_library(ecg-signal-processor-demodulator SHARED
            demodulator.cpp)
add_library(ecg-signal-processor-qrsdetection SHARED
            qrsdetection.cpp)
# Link

target_link_libraries(
            firpm_d
            log
            android
            ecg-signal-processor-demodulator
            ecg-signal-processor-qrsdetection)
```

And in the libs directory

```
# Cmake Minimum Version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(LIBS_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
#include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Eigen/)
MACRO(ADD_SUBLIB libname source_ext)
  #Compute required sources
  set(sublib_path "${LIBS_DIRECTORY}/${libname}")
  file(GLOB_RECURSE sublib_sources "${sublib_path}/src/*.${source_ext}")
  #Create library
  IF( sublib_sources )
    ADD_LIBRARY(${libname} SHARED ${sublib_sources})
  ENDIF()
  #add this library's header folder to the global include set
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${sublib_path}/include")
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${sublib_path}/")
  link_directories(${sublib_path})
ENDMACRO(ADD_SUBLIB)

ADD_SUBLIB(firpm_d "cpp")
ADD_SUBLIB(eigen "cpp")
```

It starts to compile the project, however ends up with the error.

What can cause this error, I have no idea what to try else.

Here is source code, so you can see it all structured.
https://github.com/DurianOdour/EcgProcessor

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: You are obviously not linking whatever defines the `firpm` symbol. *Or* you are linking things in incorrect order, so the symbol is not seen by the linker before the objct file or library that provides it (yes, link order matters).

Comment: @JesperJuhl, thank you for your comment, I am including firpm header file as well as source files using ADD_SUBLIB macro, this function is located in pm.h file.

Comment: the header doesn't matter here. What matters is the file *implementing* the function *and* where it occurs on the link line relative to the file that uses it. Files *using* a symbol *must* (generally) be mentioned *before* the files *providing* the symbol.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I have added source files as well `file(GLOB_RECURSE sublib_sources "${sublib_path}/src/*.${source_ext}")`

Answer (score 1):

I Have found the solution. Here it is

[Android ndk(cmake): 'undefined reference to `__android_log_write' when using log api in the second jni library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844163/android-ndkcmake-undefined-reference-to-android-log-write-when-using-log)

The problem was in the incorrect order of linking libraries.

This code works great

```
# Link
target_link_libraries(
            ecg-signal-processor
            log
            android
            firpm_d)
```

The first arguments should be a library that requires dependencies.

```
target_link_libraries(<target> [item1 [item2 [...]]]
                      [[debug|optimized|general] <item>] ...)
```